# Doing geometric-operation in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have 3 polygons (a, b, c) on layer 1 and two other polygons (1 and 2) on layer 2. Now I want to "crop and melt" my three polygons (a,b,c) with the polygons (1 and 2) that (on a new layer) I have two new areas: area I (marked in red in my picture) and area II (marked in blue in my picture). Each of my new areas has two parts.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Intersect" tool in "Geoprocessing tools" should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

With some Python code you can create a small program to make this operations and automate the process:

There are many option, I will list 3 popular ones:

1. [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org/python/) Python API
2. [Shapely](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) Python library
3. [Qgis](http://qgis.org/api/) Python API

OGR and Qgis API has a very similar structure to deal with vectors, IMO you can try Qgis API first because learning it will allow you to talk to the genie of the lamp that lives inside Qgis, he will do all the magic for you.

The Qgis API basic structure for vector is like this:
Qgis Interface -> Layers -> Features -> Geometry
You will perform the operation in the geometry level.

A good start is the [PyQgis cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/intro.html) and the python plugins available in Qgis.